# Finding objects using Activerecord with multiple conditions including a range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building a rails app and trying to find records in the DB using Activerecord. There are multiple models, most of which are one-to-many relationships but one is a many-to-many relationship and I need to be able to do a query where I can use id's from the various one-to-many models and then an array for the many-to-many.

The models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :certification
    has_many :user_certifications
    has_many :certifications, :through => :user_certifications
end

class Certification < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_certifications
    has_many :users, :through => :user_certifications
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

I can successfully do a query like:

```
User.where(['city_id = 1 AND company_id = 3'])
```

Or something using a join and an individual certification

```
User.joins(:certifications).where(['city_id = 1 AND company_id = 3 AND certification_id = 5'])
```

But since a User can have multiple certifications, I need to be able to search for city 1, company 3, and certifications 5 + 6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for `IN` clause:

```
User.joins(:certifications).where(['city_id = 1 AND company_id = 3 AND certification_id IN (5,6)'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried IN with every kind of bracket but parentheses and thought that was wrong too.

Comment: @dshamis317 no probs, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

you must use Eager Loading for avoiding n+1 query problem.

try this ->

**User.includes(:certifications).where(['city_id = 1 AND company_id = 3 AND certification_id IN (5,6)']).references(:certifications)**

see the difference previous query and latest query.